# Windows command line to parse information from a text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a text file which contains, amongst other information, lines that start with 'Password: ' . What I am looking to do is run a command line command (if possible) to parse through the .txt file to extract all of the terms that follow 'Password: ' and place them into a new textfile listing solely the passwords. The number of spaces between the word 'Password:' and the actual password varies in the entries.

I have so far used:

```
FINDSTR /L "Password: " input_file.txt > output_file.txt
```

This works well but extracts the term 'Password: ' too. From the research I have carried out, I don't believe Command Line has a built-in function to remove strings from .txt files does it as my thinking is to run the above command followed by something similar to:-

```
FINDSTR /L "Password: " input_file.txt > output_file.txt & DELSTR "Password: " output_file.txt > final_file.txt & DEL output_file.txt
```

Obviously I have invented the 'DELSTR' but as said, I would need something there to remove the string 'Password: ' from each line.

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: yeah, there are string processing capabilities built into cmd.exe: http://superuser.com/questions/228794/how-to-extract-part-of-a-string-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: Make things easier for yourself and use PowerShell instead of cmd.exe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in fact, there are some (very limited) built-in functions for string manipulation. See `set /?` for details.
No need to work with temporary files, you can parse your string directly into a variable:

(code edited to print all passwords, if there are more than one)

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /b /c:"Password: " input_file.txt') do (
  set pwd=%%a
  set "pwd=!pwd:Password: =!"
  echo !pwd!>>final_file.txt 
)
```

Comment: many thanks for this. It only seems to write the last password entry it comes across to the final_file.txt though and not all passwords. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is one problem with this code: A password with an exclamation mark is not processed correctly. The solution is using as first line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`, insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` between the two command lines with `set` and insert `endlocal` above the line with the closing round bracket.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [Stephan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2152082/stephan) code.  The For /f loop can give the result without extra string manipulation.  Also, it will remove any result that would just be spaces, causing Echo to respond with a status line, e.g. 'Echo is OFF'.   Using Echo: stops 'off' and 'on' (potential, though rather weak, passwords) from being seen as Echo parameters.

```
Setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
For /f "tokens=1* delims=: " %%a In ('Findstr /b /c:"Password: " input_file.txt') Do (
  Set pwd=%%b
  Echo:!pwd!>>final_file.txt 
)
```

Comment: There is one problem with this code: A password with an exclamation mark is not processed correctly. The solution is using as first line `setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion`,  insert `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` above and `endlocal` below the command line with command `echo`.